# How can I obtain a code with same weight codewords?

Tags: signature, implementation, post-quantum-cryptography

I want to implement "[A new one-time signature scheme
from syndrome decoding](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/017.pdf)". My first challenge is how to obtain $P$. $P$ is a generator matrix whose codewords have weight not exceeding an integer value $w$. How can one obtain this matrix for practical security parameters? Do you have any advice?